# Django Chatterbot-how to add "default-response" to settings .py?

Tags: python, django, chatterbot

In my "django" application in settings.py I have:

```
CHATTERBOT = {
    'name': 'bot1',
    'storage_adapter': "chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    'logic_adapters': [
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
    ]
}
```

How do I add the auto default response parameter?
I tried countless ways but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I just added the 'default-response' attribute like this:

```
CHATTERBOT = {
    'name': 'bot1',
    'default_response': 'How can I help you?',
    'storage_adapter': "chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    'logic_adapters': [
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
    ]
}
```